# R replacing values from one dataframe with values from another with multiple instances

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to replace values in my main dataframe with values from another dataframe. This is a mock up of the problem:

MAIN DF

```
    index=c(1:10)
    SKU = c('I-1','I-9','I-4','I-1','I-6','I-9','I-2','I-3','I-8','I-9')
    COST=c(17,15,10,NA,12,NA,8,12,10,NA)
    main = data.frame(index, SKU, COST)
    main
```

FILL DF

```
    SKU = c('I-1','I-2','I-3','I-4','I-6','I-8','I-9')
    COST=c(19,8,12,10,12,10,11)
    fill = data.frame(SKU, COST)
    fill
```

I'm trying to fill in the NAs in the COST column of 'main' based on the SKU of 'fill'. You might notice that the main$COST associated with main$SKU doesn't always match those of the 'fill' df. This condition is present in my actual dataset. In my actual dataset a SKU can have multiple costs due to sales promotions. In my actual dataset I generated my fill df by aggregating the COST values of my SKUs and calculating the mean so only a single value is associated with each SKU.
I can't seem to get the code to fill all values though. This is what I tried on this mock up:

```
    main$COST[is.na(main$COST)] <- fill$COST[match(main$SKU, fill$SKU)]
    main
```

I'm expecting to see indexes 4,6 & 10 filled with the values from the 'fill' df, 19 & 10 based off their respective SKUs, but the value at index 6 is still NA. So from what I can tell, the code only replaces on a one-to-one basis, only replacing one instance of the NA associated with the SKU from 'fill'. SKU I-9 has 2 NA instances though. Can anyone explain why and/or how to fix this issue?

Comment: index 6 has SKU I-9, which is not in `fill`.  What cost do you expect for that?

Comment: I expect that I made a mistake. Let me fix it and try the code again. Thanks for the catch.

Comment: @JonSpring Fixed the code. Still not getting the expected output though. I'm getting the correct results at index 4&6 (19,21), but index 10 is giving me 10 as the COST value.

Comment: Check the solution I posted.  It solves the problem at hand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
main |>
  left_join(fill, by = "SKU") |>
  transmute(index, SKU, COST = coalesce(COST.x, COST.y))
```

Result

```
   index SKU COST
1      1 I-1   17
2      2 I-9   15
3      3 I-4   10
4      4 I-1   19
5      5 I-6   12
6      6 I-9   11
7      7 I-2    8
8      8 I-3   12
9      9 I-8   10
10    10 I-9   11
```

Comment: Thanks Jon. I didn't realize R had some SQL-like features.

Comment: COST.x represents main & y fill?

Comment: Right, when dplyr joins two tables with the same names (and we're not using them as join keys), the first same-named column gets `.x` and the 2nd `.y`

Comment: You should have been the one to post a solution with  `row_patch`. Anyway hope you know about it and use it in the future

Comment: I did not but it is good and right that it should exist, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Although this has been accepted as the anser, you should definitely used the function  `dplyr::row_patch` ie

```
library(dplyr)
rows_patch(main, fill)

   index SKU COST
1      1 I-1   17
2      2 I-9   15
3      3 I-4   10
4      4 I-1   19
5      5 I-6   12
6      6 I-9   11
7      7 I-2    8
8      8 I-3   12
9      9 I-8   10
10    10 I-9   11
```

Comment: It certainly is the way. A frakin one-liner!

Comment: @onyambu First of all, Thank you, RStudio is giving me a message, 'Matching, by = "index"'. Would I be correct in assuming this would work as an optional arg I could use to set the matching criteria to another col. ie. rows_patch(x,y, by = 'SKU')?

Comment: @JoeMcsweeney You can use the `by` argument similar way we use it in the `*_join` functions. Yes you need to match by `SKU`in this case. ie note that `SKU` is the common column between the two. `index` column is not present in the fill data. and yes you could set different matching criterias, as long as each row is uniquely defined

Answer (score 1):

```
rm(list = ls())

index=c(1:10)
SKU = c('I-1','I-9','I-4','I-1','I-6','I-9','I-2','I-3','I-8','I-9')
COST=c(17,15,10,NA,12,NA,8,12,10,NA)
main = data.frame(index, SKU, COST)
main

SKU = c('I-1','I-2','I-3','I-4','I-6','I-8','I-9')
COST=c(19,8,12,10,12,10,11)
fill = data.frame(SKU, COST)
fill

# where are the NAs? Get the row index.
SKU_NA_index <- which(is.na(main$COST))  

# Get the corresponding SKU identity
SKU_NA <- main[which(is.na(main$COST)), "SKU"] 

# Get the corresponding value from "fill" according to the SKU identity
fill_the_NA <- fill[match(SKU_NA, fill$SKU), "COST"]

# Replace the value to the "main" dataframe
main[SKU_NA_index, "COST"] <- fill_the_NA
```